# Applying same function on multiple files

Tags: r

I am new R programmer. 
I've got thousands of csv files in one folder. Date column of all csv files have different format than I need. (I am doing another manupalations after changing format)

```
directory <- "/my/path/"   #(all csv files)   
file_names <- list.files(directory)

mutate(Date = as.POSIXct(Date, format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S"))
```

Now I need to apply this function for all columns of all csv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `lapply`, read the file, change the `Date` column and return the modified dataframe.

```
all_files <- lapply(file_names, function(x) {
    df <- read.csv(x)
    df$Date <- as.POSIXct(df$Date, format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")
    df
})
```

`all_files` would be list of dataframes on which further manipulation can be done.

---

If you want to write the dataframe back after changing the format we can use `write.csv`

```
lapply(file_names, function(x) {
   df <- read.csv(x)
   df$Date <- as.POSIXct(df$Date, format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")
   write.csv(df, x)
})
```

Comment: I defined that Date column is factor, should I first change it into Date format? Now my code format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S" returns NA value

Comment: @MeruyertYechshan It should work even if it is a factor. See `as.POSIXct(factor("21.03.2019 00:10:10"), format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")`. Are you sure you have the correct format? Can you show first few rows of any of your csv file ?

Comment: Yes, now it works. I guess it was my trouble. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

We can do this in `tidyverse`

```
library(readr)
library(purrr)
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
map(file_names, ~ read_csv(.x) %>%
                     mutate(Date = dmy_hms(Date)) %>%
                     write_csv(path = .x))
```